# My simple regression is homoscedastic - should I use robust standard errors or both?

Tags: r, regression, robust, robust-standard-error

[image]I've been asked to estimate the following simple regression with the 'appropriate' standard errors at 5% sig level and report the results in a table:

```
logGDPcapita=β0+β1 AvExprRisk+u

                                  Dependent variable:     
                              ----------------------------
                                        logpgp95          
                                   (1)            (2)     
avexpr                           0.522***      0.522***   
                                 (0.061)        (0.050)   
Constant                         4.660***      4.660***   
                                 (0.409)        (0.320)

Observations                        64            64      
R2                                0.540          0.540    
Adjusted R2                       0.533          0.533    
Residual Std. Error (df = 62)     0.713          0.713    
F Statistic (df = 1; 62)        72.816***      72.816***  
==========================================================
Note:                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I used the Breusch-Pagan test and found p was much greater than 0.05 (0.39) which suggests homoscedasticity. However, most of the research I've done says I should almost always include robust standard errors, and there are omitted variables in this regression so I am skeptical that it is homoskedastic, is it appropriate to include both? Also, what does it mean if my robust standard errors are smaller?

Comment: Showing a graph would increase the evidence here. Are these cross-sectional data or time series?

Comment: I'd say your biggest puzzle is nothing to do with SEs or P-values. It's why there is apparently a bunch of 5 values with large negative residuals that may tell you something.